# iptables' DROP rule doesn't work

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to add this rule as the final, after all the other rules that allow the traffic.

```
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

And this rule blocks everything.

When connecting through the web port 80, nginx throws "502 Bad Gateway". My guess that it somehow blocks some port like the database which causes the application not to respond?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you are setting this rule to a different interface? Look at `iptables -L -v` for more information.

Comment: sorry I just edited the question, because it was badly formulated.

Comment: no, I allow everything like port 22, 80, 3000 etc, and adding this DROP rule as the last one. I ran nmap localhost, and basically allowed all the relevant ports from it's output. Possibly I'm blocking something on which the web app relies?

Comment: If that rule is blocking everything, then your rules to permit traffic are incomplete, broken, or wrong.  We probably cannot do anything to help you without knowing more about the rest of your rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think about adding iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT as first rule. Typically you can allow loopback connections without worsening security (but be aware of consequences).

Comment: +1, My bets are on relevant local traffic not being allowed.

Comment: +1 - i wasn't even aware that loopback was handled by iptables - seems obvious now, but good thing to mention

Answer (score 1):

Additionally you could simply set the default policy of the chain if this is the only thing you want to accomplish:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

To answer your question though, no, iptables doesn't just decide 'not to work'. Your rules are probably wrong. If you update your question with the relevant information we can help you further.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the vote if that was you :) I figured kupson was right since you mentioned the database, but I figured the comment would be helpful anyway :)